# Literaturverzeichnis changed to Literatur upon texlive update

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

In a German book I edit, a recent update of my texlive installation (from ubuntu-eoan default to ubuntu-focal default) incurred a change in the PDF from "Literaturverzeichnis" to "Literatur" as the title of the bibliography. I have not touched my LaTeX files at all during this change, so, any idea which package might have incurred this change? I have MANY; a choice is displayed below. Here is how it starts:

```
\documentclass[deutsch,envcountsame,envcountsect,vecarrow]{svmono}% v5.6, local file, somewhat hacked (as the original version has bugs), and lying in my local directory
% ... lots of junk here ...
\usepackage[russian,greek,USenglish,british,french,norsk,dutch,latin,german,ngerman]{babel}
% ... more junk ...
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic,sortcites=true,maxnames=99,useprefix=true,dateabbrev=true,autolang=other]{biblatex}
% ... more junk ...
\usepackage[unicode,pdftitle={My Book Title},hidelinks,pdfauthor={Author list}]{hyperref}
% ... more junk ...
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}
% ... junk continues ...
```

The file svmono.cls originally was taken from https://www.springer.com/gp/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/resources-guidelines/book-manuscript-guidelines/manuscript-preparation/5636 by clicking on LaTeX template > monographs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very vague question.

In theory, the code responsible for this could hide pretty much everywhere.

In practice, not a lot of packages try to interface with `biblatex` in a way that should make a difference here. Indeed, I am not actively aware of *any* package that would try to manipulate the bibliography heading in the way you describe.

"Literaturverzeichnis" is the long form of both the `bibliography` and `references` bibstring in `german.lbx`. "Literatur" is the short form. ([A short look at the "blame" on GitHub shows that it has been that way at least for eight years.](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blame/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/german.lbx))

One plausible explanation is that you switched from long forms of the bibstrings to short forms (that is controlled by the `biblatex` option `abbreviate`).

---

Here is an idea: When you search for `Literatur` in `svmono.cls` (2009/12/17 v5.5 available from https://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics?SGWID=0-40292-2-122598-0; I had a short look at `svmono.cls` v5.6 from your link, it's structurally the same for this issue) you'll find

```
\def\switcht@deutsch{\svlanginfo
 \def\abstractname{Zusammenfassung}%
 \def\ackname{Danksagung}%
 \def\andname{und}%
 \def\lastandname{ und}%
 \def\appendixname{Anhang}%
 \def\bibname{Literaturverzeichnis}%
 \def\chaptername{Kapitel}%
 \def\claimname{Behauptung}%
 \def\conjecturename{Hypothese}%
 \def\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}%
 \def\corollaryname{Korollar}%
%\def\definitionname{Definition}%
 \def\emailname{E-mail}%
 \def\examplename{Beispiel}%
 \def\exercisename{\"Ubung}%
 \def\figurename{Abb.}%
 \def\forewordname{Geleitwort}%
 \def\keywordname{{\bf Schl\"usselw\"orter:}}%
 \def\indexname{Sachverzeichnis}%
%\def\lemmaname{Lemma}%
 \def\contriblistname{Mitarbeiter}%
 \def\listfigurename{Abbildungsverzeichnis}%
 \def\listtablename{Tabellenverzeichnis}%
 \def\mailname{{\it Correspondence to\/}:}%
 \def\noteaddname{Nachtrag}%
 \def\notename{Anmerkung}%
 \def\partname{Teil}%
 \def\prefacename{Vorwort}%
%\def\problemname{Problem}%
 \def\proofname{Beweis}%
 \def\propertyname{Eigenschaft}%
%\def\propositionname{Proposition}%
 \def\questionname{Frage}%
 \def\refname{Literaturverzeichnis}%
 \def\remarkname{Anmerkung}%
 \def\seename{siehe}%
 \def\solutionname{L\"osung}%
 \def\subclassname{{\it Subject Classifications\/}:}%
 \def\tablename{Tabelle}%
%\def\theoremname{Theorem}%
}
```

In particular this macro defines both `\refname` and `\bibname` to expand to `Literaturverzeichnis`.

The macro `\switcht@deutsch` is mentioned again in

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifundefined{url}{\def\url#1{#1}}{}%
\@ifpackageloaded{babel}{%
\@ifundefined{extrasamerican}{}{\addto\extrasamerican{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasaustralian}{}{\addto\extrasaustralian{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasbritish}{}{\addto\extrasbritish{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrascanadian}{}{\addto\extrascanadian{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasenglish}{}{\addto\extrasenglish{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasnewzealand}{}{\addto\extrasnewzealand{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasUKenglish}{}{\addto\extrasUKenglish{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasUSenglish}{}{\addto\extrasUSenglish{\switcht@albion}}%
\@ifundefined{captionsfrench}{}{\addto\captionsfrench{\switcht@francais}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasgerman}{}{\addto\extrasgerman{\switcht@deutsch}}%
\@ifundefined{extrasngerman}{}{\addto\extrasngerman{\switcht@deutsch}}%
}{\switcht@@therlang}%
}
```

So, `svmono` appends this definition to `\extrasgerman` and `\extrasngerman` (if available) in an `\AtBeginDocument` hook.

`biblatex` uses `\refname` and `\bibname` to typeset the bibliography headings. But `biblatex` also tries to populate `\refname` and `\bibname` with its own bibstrings. This is done with code that also ultimately ends up in `\extrasngerman` (if your document language is `ngerman`). And that's where a recent change in `biblatex` comes in. In v3.14 the code that makes that happen is executed in a `\AtBeginDocument` hook. In older versions it used the `\AtEndPreamble` hook. See for the details https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/d12f8a045ab5dc1d768b6b6bbd5e65968fb9b699. Because the `\AtBeginDocument` hook is executed in the order it was populated, this means that `biblatex` v3.14's language definitions are added to `\extrasngerman` after `svmono`'s. In older versions of `biblatex` that used `\AtEndPreamble` `biblatex`'s definitions would have come in *before* `svmono`'s.

This means that in old versions of `biblatex` the definition of `\bibname` and `\refname` from `svmono` prevail, while with new versions of `biblatex` `biblatex`'s versions prevail. That's why you get "Literatur" now: It's what `biblatex` would have always given you if no one else had modified `\extrasngerman`.

---

Since `biblatex` has full control over the bibliography heading now, the way to get "Literaturverzeichnis" back if you otherwise want to stick to `abbreviate=true,` is probably to add

```
\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{%
  bibliography     = {Literaturverzeichnis},
  references       = {Literaturverzeichnis},
}
```

to your preamble (after loading `biblatex`).

Comment: @Just_A_Man The default value of the `abbreviate` option (the option responsible for this) has not been changed in eight years. It has always been `abbreviate=true,`, which means that you'd expect the short form "Literatur"  in the output.